# error 13 . Permission error in jupiter notebook when i tried to read excel file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to read an excel file which contains data (for my project of data visualisation ) but I keep getting
`PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission Denied` 
I tried moving my file to another folder/disk but still getting this error.
Furthermore I checked my ransomeware protection but it is already off. Details of the error are attached below. 
 
[image: attachment]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you did not set correctly the name of your excel file, the python error is about a folder and not a file (it does not end with .xlsx)

Comment: yes thanks a lot man i figured it out. I was copying the location of the file using right click properties but it was not adding the file name and extension at the end, Jeej what a relief !! THANKS MAN

Comment: @shubhamkandpal so you can accept my answer :) your welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem but not the same as the above problem.

How I resolved my problem:

Troubleshooting Steps:

- Verify Permissions: Double-check file permissions and grant write
  access if needed.
- Close the File: Make sure the file is not open in any other
  applications.
- Run with Elevated Privileges: Try running your Python script or
  terminal with administrator rights.
- Check File Path: Ensure the file path in your code is correct and
  accessible. Review Code: Double-check your code for any errors in
  file handling.